# Python - How to print how many websites support each ciphersuite request

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, encryption

So I have 20 websites in my `hosts.txt` file which each runs a `WeakCipher , KnownCipher, ModernCipher` to test if a connection can be established.

This is a school assignment where I'm told to test 3 kinds of ciphers.

**How can I make it print how many websites support each ciphersuite?**

```
import socket
import ssl
import grequests
import re


WeakCipher = 'NULL-MD5'

KnownCipher = 'DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384'

ModernCipher = 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384'

#Read from txt file and convert it into a List.
List = open("C:\\Users\\Farzad\\Desktop\\hosts.txt").read().splitlines()

#async method to do more than 1 URL at a time
rs = (grequests.get(url) for url in List)
requests = grequests.map(rs)


for response in requests:
    urlfix = re.compile(r"https?://(www\.)?")
    urlre = urlfix.sub('', response.url).strip().strip('/')

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.set_ciphers(WeakCipher)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=urlre)
    try:
        ssl_sock.connect((urlre, 443))
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR:", response.url, "DOES NOT SUPPORT YOUR WEAK CIPHER")
    else:
        print(response.url,"CONNECTION ESTABLISHED WITH YOUR WEAK CIPHER")


    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.set_ciphers(KnownCipher)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=urlre)
    try:
        ssl_sock.connect((urlre, 443))
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR:", response.url, "DOES NOT SUPPORT YOUR MODERN CIPHER")
    else:
        print(response.url,"CONNECTION ESTABLISHED WITH YOUR KNOWN CIPHER" )


    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    context.set_ciphers(ModernCipher)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=urlre)
    try:
        ssl_sock.connect((urlre, 443))
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR:", response.url, "DOES NOT SUPPORT YOUR MODERN CIPHER" '\n')
    else:
        print(response.url,"CONNECTION ESTABLISHED WITH YOUR MODERN CIPHER" '\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a bash script to test cipher suites. It should get a list of supported cipher suites from OpenSSL and tries to connect using each one. If the handshake is successful, it should prints YES. If the handshake isn't successful, it prints NO, followed by the OpenSSL error text.

nmap has a sample script you can refer to.
Nmap with ssl-enum-ciphers

```
WeakCipher = 'NULL-MD5'

t_weak=0

context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.set_ciphers(WeakCipher)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=urlre)
try:
    ssl_sock.connect((urlre, 443))
except Exception as e:
    print("ERROR:", response.url, "DOES NOT SUPPORT YOUR WEAK CIPHER")
else:
    t_weak +=1
    print(response.url,"CONNECTION ESTABLISHED WITH YOUR WEAK CIPHER")

print("Number of websites with Weak cipher", t_weak)
```

Comment: Thank you but I want this to be a python script only and my script already does all this, except for printing amounts of handshakes like 6/20 with the weak cipher or 15/20 handshakes with the known cipher.

Comment: So you need like a summary report at the end?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I want.

Comment: Why don't you add a counter inside each try catch statement and print the summary at the end. The counter will increment each time the particular try statement is running.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it